# Contents in PDF bookmarks

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, koma-script, bookmarks

I am using KOMA-Script (`scrreprt`) and `hyperref`.

The PDF bookmarks are generated nicely from the table of contents, but I would like an extra *Contents* bookmark to point to the table of contents itself (without including an entry in the table of contents) - like the KOMA manual itself.

(Also list of figures and list of tables if I include them)

What is the best way to do this?

I could add a `\pdfbookmark` manually but I'm not sure how to get it to point correctly to the start of the section - if I do it after it will be on the wrong page (multipage toc), if I do before it will be the page before (since `\tableofcontents` does `\cleardoublepage`?). I guess I have to redefine `\tableofcontents` somehow.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following code should create a correct ToC bookmark for both `scrreprt` and `scrbook`:

```
\makeatletter
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\tableofcontents}{%
  \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
  \pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{toc}%
}{}{}%
\makeatother
```

Comment: For the lists of figures and tables, the above code should work by replacing `\tableofcontents` with `\listoffigures` resp. `\listoftables`, `\contentsname` with `\listfigurename` resp. `\listtablename`, `toc` with `lof` resp. `lot`.

Comment: Where would this go: in the document preamble, after a certain `\usepackage` command, or in the document somewhere?

Answer (score 40):

A general way for base classes using `\addtocontents` would be:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect{\pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{toc}}}
```

Similar for lof and lot with `\listfigurename` and `\listtablename`.

But, since KOMA-Script uses `tocbasic`, this would be better way and very simple:

```
\BeforeTOCHead[toc]{{\pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{toc}}}
```

Just this line will get you the bookmark for the table of contents.

Here's a compilable example, where `\BeforeTOCHead` is used to create bookmarks for *all* such lists like toc, lof and lot.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\BeforeTOCHead{%
  \cleardoublepage
    \edef\@tempa{%
      \noexpand\pdfbookmark[0]{\list@fname}{\@currext}%
    }\@tempa
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter{One}
text
\end{document}
```

No redefinition of `\tableofcontents` and no etoolbox would be required. Different names by babel are supported.

Comment: I tried \BeforeTOCHead[toc]{{\pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{toc}}}
 but the bookmark seems to link to the blank left hand page before to toc (which starts on right hand side)

Comment: Oh never mind \BeforeTOCHead[toc]{{\cleardoublepage\pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{toc}}} seems to do it. Thanks very much

Comment: Hmm, the code for all bookmarks doesn't work with the `listings` package, it points to the right page but the bookmark's name is empty.

Comment: How to make the name of the bookmark be the same as the TOC's header it refers to? At the moment, I have the header in one language and the name of the bookmark in the PDF in English ("Contents").

Comment: @Anton: Did you load babel, as in e.g. `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`?

Comment: @dapperdan Yep, `babel` has its language and TOC as a header is in local language, but not in the bookmarks.

Comment: @Anton: Sorry, then I guess you will have to post a new question with a MWE, because I cannot reproduce your problem with Stefan's example. Let us know here if you do, please. You might also want to check the order of your commands in the preamble, i.e. load `babel` early, though I doubt that this is the cause of your problem.

Comment: `\pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{toc}` ([_level_=1](https://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html#x1-160004.1.1)) arranges the added entries in line with the normal chapter/section bookmarks. Otherwise you can collapse the "normals" with the added ones.

Comment: Your solution is great, but as [neo](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/6255/neo) has already mentioned in his comment, it does produce an empty label for `\lstlistoflistings`. Do you have an idea why and/or could provide a fix?

Comment: I'm trying NOT to use KOMA scripts. Adding the line `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect{\pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{toc}}}` right above `\tableofcontents` in the document body worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 14):

With KOMA scrreprt here are documentclass options for adding bibliography and the 'list of's to the table of contents:

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    bibliography=totoc,
    listof=totoc,
    final
]{scrreprt}
```

If you want to just add a pdf bookmark, you can use the command `\pdfbookmark`:

```
\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents
```

Comment: Although I prefer this solution to the other given answers, because it makes use of KOMA-options, the bookmark might point the end of page right before the TOC. To solve this, change it to: `\clearpage\phantomsection\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents`