# hyperref vs includepdf

Tags: hyperref, page-numbering, bookmarks, pdfpages

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{mwrep}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.5}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{*}{}{}{}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\tableofcontents}{%
  \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
  \pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{toc}%
}{}{}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
%\begin{titlepage}
%\includepdf[pages=1-]{titlepage.pdf}
%\end{titlepage}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A}
a\dots
\chapter{B}c\dots
\chapter{D}
d\dots
\chapter{E}
e\dots

\begin{thebibliography}{999}
\bibitem{bib1}Author:
\emph{Title},
Publisher, Year
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Everything works good, I have nice links in pdf viewer. But when I uncomment three lines with `includepdf` I got errors when trying to compile. `titlepage.pdf` contains two pages but I don't think this is relevant.

Second question, how can I add something to bookmars (generated by `hyperref`)? I want to add <s>ToC as well as</s> first page of `titlepage.pdf`.

Also, adding `titlepage.pdf` brokes page numeration in pdf viewer (bookmarks). When I try to go to page 7, I to to page 5 instead. Can it be fixed? (I know it is the result of adding two extra pages at the beginning).

Also, `hyperref` changes Polish letters.
I have chapter `Wstęp` but in bookmarks there is `Wstep`.
Can it be fixed?

EDIT:
Bookmark to ToC [solved](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1820/contents-in-pdf-bookmarks).

EDIT 2:
One more thing that I need is adding included pdf's first page to bookmarks.

Comment: As for the Polish diacritics in pdf bookmarks: AFAIR, you can't get them, since adobe reader (or at least its older versions) displays bookmarks with a built-in font with very small repertoire of characters.  So substituting "Wstep" for "Wstęp" is perfectly reasonable.

(Although I'm by no means expert as far as pdf format goes - this may as well be wrong nowadays, pdf wizards please correct me if its the case!)

Comment: @mbork: Yes, you're wrong. :) @Ichibann: Pass `unicode` option to `hyperref` package, but you possibly should convert your doc to UTF-8 before (and obviously change then `inputenc` option to `utf8`).

Comment: I converted my documents to `utf8` in Notepad++, but now LEd wont work with them :(. It displays `WstÄ™p` instead of `Wstęp` (but compiles correctly)

Comment: Is LEd maintained even at all now? By looking at its page it looks like it is pretty dead. `Currently we are working on: adding support for Unicode and UTF-7, UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 encodings,`... Notepad++ isn't best tool for conversion, because it's damn easy to screw there encoding (BTW you should go w/o BOM). Also add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to your preamble apart from fixed `inputenc` setting. You may also go with `T1,OT4`, but it is more tricky if you use some other fonts, thus it requires switching via `\fontencoding{T1}`. Gain is only in a few KBs, so I suggest sticking just to `T1`.

Comment: I think Notepad++ didn't screw anything here. What LaTeX editor supports UTF8?

Comment: (g)Vim? winefish? Texmaker? Actually any _normal_ editor supports UTF8.

Comment: What does those dommands (`\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` etc) do?

Comment: See _Why should I use \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}?_ http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664/why-should-i-use-usepackaget1fontenc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the "errors" are like

```
pdfTeX warning
 (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{page.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
```

then they are solved by saying

```
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Alph}
\begin{titlepage}
\includepdf[pages=1-]{titlepage.pdf}
\end{titlepage}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\tableofcontents
```

The reason is that **hyperref** finds two "page 1", which is not the case if we order LaTeX to number with letters the first two pages.

Comment: That worked :). Can you help me with bookmark to included pdf?

Comment: You can just add a `\pdfbookmark{Title page}{}` before `\includepdf`.