# How to add a navigation window to a LaTeX generated PDF document?

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

Some ( if not most ) pdf ebooks have the option to view the table of contents in a left navigation window. I would like to add this option to my document as well. **Question: How to add a navigation window to a LaTeX generated PDF document?**

Comment: well, I believe you can add bookmarks using `hyperref`. The regular navigation with sectioning commands is done automatically, I believe. At least I have never had to do something special to get it and acrobat shows a navigation pane with contents on all of my documents.

Comment: You can always switch on/off the navigation pane, but every pdf has a default view. The option for showing the navigation pane by default is `pdfpagemode=UseOutlines`. Anyway, you can tell Acrobat to override the documents default settings.

Comment: @ndroock1 maybe the following is also interesting for you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1820/contents-in-pdf-bookmarks/42352#42352

Comment: After following the steps below, the index still did not show for me.  It turned out to be a problem of not re-loading the file.  I was using Evince which automatically updates the view when the file is changed (awesome for working in $\LaTeX$) but the navigation window did not show until I actually closed and reopened the file.  Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use a `hyperref` package. You'll have to start with a fresh .tex file compilation; i.e. no .aux file. You can add several option to the package as well, read the [`hyperref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) documentation. I presume you have your document well sectioned, the `hyperref` package generates the TOC entries in your viewer for chapters, bibliography, sections, abstract...etc.
You might find different outcomes of TOC depending on your `documentclass`.

---

Here's a setup I use:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftex,colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue}
\usepackage{hypcap}
```

I added the last one as an extra since links should always anchor at the image not the caption.

Comment: I create my documents with TeXnicCenter, I would be lost otherwise. I hope it is compatible because it does generate .aux files. But let me have a look at hyperref first.

Comment: @ndroock1: The TeX file will generate an aux file eitherway, what I'm saying is that it has to generate a new one. You could simply delete the aux file and let it compile with a new one after you add the `hyperref` package.

Comment: Hi, I tried it and I see nothing visible change, particularly nothing any navigation pane or bookmark index. I use pdflatex to generate the pdf file.

Answer (score 32):

As has been said, you need to use the `hyperref` package.
Just add the following lines to your preamble:

```
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={Your title here},
    pdfauthor={Your name here},
    pdfsubject={Your subject here},
    pdfkeywords={keyword1, keyword2},
    bookmarksnumbered=true,     
    bookmarksopen=true,         
    bookmarksopenlevel=1,       
    colorlinks=true,            
    pdfstartview=Fit,           
    pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,    % this is the option you were lookin for
    pdfpagelayout=TwoPageRight
}
```

Usually, hyperref should be loaded as the last package (but every rule has [exceptions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before)).

Comment: +1 for [the link to the exceptions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before)

Comment: I am sorry, but I tried this and nothing has changed. There is still nothing navigation pane. Absolutely nothing.