# AASTEX62 doesn't allow pdf to contain a table of contents.

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, hyperref, pdf, aastex

I am trying to compile a pdf from Latex source using TexStudio, which calls pdflatex. Take a look at the following code:

```
%\documentclass[]{aastex62}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{The First}
\section{The Second}
\subsection{Section 2.1}

\end{document}
```

Now, when I use the article class, I get a pdf that has the contents embedded:
[Look, a working TOC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPqb1.png)

Whereas if I use the aastex62 class, I get nothing:
[Nope, nothing to see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kICOb.png)

Some things that I know:
1. aastex already calls hyperref, so I don't have to import it again. The issue I'm having isn't sensitive to this change.
2. This issue also happens in Overleaf, so it shouldn't be in any way dependent on my personal setup. [Here is a minimum working overleaf example](https://www.overleaf.com/9438132834pqpptpsfxtgw)
3. This issue is similar/the same as [this issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42343/how-to-add-a-navigation-window-to-a-latex-generated-pdf-document), but the solution there does not work with the aastex62 document class.

So, what do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: You need us (i'm one of the AAS Data Editors who work on AASTeX) to fix the bug preventing ToCs. It is an #a11y issue that we need to fix (and will in v6.3). If you have additional input then please! => https://github.com/AASJournals/AASTeX60/issues/72

Comment: @Gus Do you want me to delete my answer? I am happy to if it is bad advice here

Comment: @Gus I was able to use your link to fix my problem. I just changed the line in the class file to Bookmarks = True, and now I have what I want. If you were to put that comment as an answer, I would mark it as the solution. Thanks

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm never sure of the right SE/SO operational protocols! It is accurate to say that this is a bug and not our style preference, however.

Comment: @GillyGumption Again, I'm never sure of SE/SO protocols, but I'll put this bug fix as an answer and hopefully that will help others who find the solution via this platform.

Answer (score 1):

I am one of the maintainers of the `AASTeX` package; this is a known bug with the workaround given below.

For reasons as yet undetermined, the fact that the `bookmarks=false` is fixed in our AASTeX class file means that it cannot be overridden by the user via `\hypersetup`. Other `hyperref` parameters, e.g., `linkcolor=` can be overridden via `\hypersetup`, but not `bookmarks`.

Thus the fix is to hack `aastex62.cls` to change `bookmarks=true`.  We will be fixing this in v6.3 of this classfile because a Table of Content is an important accessibility feature, which we should not be impeding.

This bug was originally raised and diagnosed (by me) here: https://github.com/AASJournals/AASTeX60/issues/72