# How to include table of contents into a table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I would like to know how to include table of contents into a table of contents....

I have an example of how to spoof it into the toc - using \phantomsection - but it seems like when i have a long document the link goes a bit wrong - ie. it links to a couple of pages before.....

```
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
\tableofcontents
```

---

**Example:**

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts,dsfont}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman} 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{titlepage}
{\Large
\begin{center}
{\bf XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
\end{center}
}
\end{titlepage}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
\tableofcontents


\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{XXXXX}
\label{chXXXXX}

\section{Introduction}\label{chXXXXX_Intro}
BLAH BLAH BLAH. 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%--------------------
\setboolean{@twoside}{false}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of using `\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}` you can load the [`tocbibind`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocbibind) package.

Comment: Just out of interest: why does one want to do so? When I'm reading the TOC, I should actually be able to find the TOC without having to look into the TOC… as you see, this is a bit self-referencial.

Comment: Fair point.  I guess the point is more - not so much to add it to the table of contents instead to the bookmarks in the e version - for easy navigation.  It seemed a bit weird when i looked at the bookmarks that it noted the abstract, talks/papers, and then no bookmarks through to the first chapter - missing the TOC, lists of figures, tables etc. Adding it to the table of contents as well is nice - because it makes the bookmarks+TOC the same. (I should note I'm writing my thesis - it has a lot of crap required at the beginning).  Anyway - I love self referential stuff - just like this comment.

Comment: Looks like your question was some kind of [xy problem](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-does-xy-problem-mean). The problem that you state in your comment may be solve in [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1820/contents-in-pdf-bookmarks)

Comment: Therefore I put a link to an explanation behind it. Here it is again: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-does-xy-problem-mean

Comment: An explicit page break (`\newpage`, `\clearpage`, or `\cleardoublepage`) before `\phantomsection` is missing to ensure that `\phantomsection` is at the top of the right page.

Comment: @Benedikt Bauer, sorry - didn't see the first link.  Perhaps it is strictly an xy problem - in that i wanted a bookmark, and was aiming to get it through the TOC. Although if I'm honest I'm pretty happy to have the solution to x and y - for the reason i mentioned above - so the bookmarks+TOC are the same.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok.... Superfast answer\comment from Gonzalo Medina

> Instead of using \phantomsection
>   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents} you can load the tocbibind
>   package. – Gonzalo Medina 3 mins ago

---

**Example becomes:**

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts,dsfont}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{tocbibind}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{titlepage}
{\Large
\begin{center}
{\bf XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
\end{center}
}
\end{titlepage}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{XXXXX}
\label{chXXXXX}

\section{Introduction}\label{chXXXXX_Intro}
BLAH BLAH BLAH.

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%--------------------
\setboolean{@twoside}{false}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for a solution that didn't as much as make me change my source file but to add an include.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the KOMA-script class, then the following is recommended over the `tocbibind` package:

```
\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}
```