# Have tableofcontents as PDF bookmark, but not lstlistoflistings

Tags: table-of-contents, listings, bookmarks

I want to have the "Contents" section appear as a PDF bookmark.

I have found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1820/contents-in-pdf-bookmarks), and the following generally works:

```
\makeatletter
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\tableofcontents}{%
  \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
  \pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{toc}%
}{}{}%
\makeatother
```

**But** now I have a new problem. It also adds a bookmark for "List of Listings". I have the following sequence:

```
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\lstlistoflistings
```

I want *only* the first item (`\tableofcontents`) to appear as PDF bookmark. Interestingly, the list-of-figures and list-of-tables do not get bookmarks, which is great. But unfortunately the list-of-listings seems implemented differently and does appear. How can I make the list-of-listings go away again from my PDF bookmarks?

---

I already have this customisation, perhaps it can be further adjusted?

```
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{List of Listings}
```

Or I could "undo" the `\pretocmd` before `\lstlistoflistings`?

Comment: It would just be awesome if you could provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv). Admittedly I'm lazy and don't want to write a document from scratch... and maybe you're using special packages that could influence possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `\pretocmd`, simply prepend that stuff to `\tableofcontents` directly. That way, the list of listings is not affected. So:

```
\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi%
\pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{toc}%
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\lstlistoflistings
```