# Can hyperref be made to include the TOC in a PDF contents navigator?

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, hyperref, pdf

Simple minimal document

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Preface}
This is the preface.

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter One}
This is chapter one.

\end{document}
```

By using `hyperref`, pdflatex produces a "Contents" section in the PDF file. This handy navigator does not include the TOC itself, for this document it only contains "Chapter One". I want my PDF Contents to include a link to the on-page TOC. (Naturally I don't want the on-page TOC to contain itself.) Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried: putting`\pdfbookmark[1]{Name}{Anchor}` just before calling `\tableofcontents` where [1] is the level at which the bookmark should appear. You may need a `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage` before setting the bookmark to ensure it points to the right position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `tocbibind` will add the `ToC` to the `ToC` itself, since `hyperref` is loaded, there will be `ToC` entry in the bookmarks itself. If the `ToC` should not appear in the `ToC`, temporarily decrease the `tocdepth` counter to `-2` which means that nothing will be written to the `ToC`, use the old `\latextableofcontents` command and write an increased value for the `tocdepth` counter to the `ToC` file.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{bookmark}

\AtBeginDocument{%
\let\latextableofcontents\tableofcontents

\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-2}}
  \latextableofcontents%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}
}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Preface}
This is the preface.

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter One}
This is chapter one.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `tocbibind` is not recommended if you are using a KOMA-Script class.

Comment: @Schweinebacke: Well, I know that. I don't recommend KOMA in turn ;-)

Answer (score 8):

You can use `\BeforeTOCHead` to add a `\pdfbookmark` just before the heading of the table of contents. You need an additional `\cleardoublepage` before the `\pdfbookmark` otherwise the bookmark will be added to the last page of chapter preface.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\BeforeTOCHead[toc]{\cleardoublepage\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{toc}}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Preface}
This is the preface.

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter One}
This is chapter one.

\end{document}
```

If you want similar additions for the list of figures or the list of tables, you may use:

```
\BeforeTOCHead[lof]{\cleardoublepage\pdfbookmark{\listfigurename}{lof}}
\BeforeTOCHead[lot]{\cleardoublepage\pdfbookmark{\listtablename}{lot}}
```

Alternatively you can add option `listof=totoc` to `\documentclass`, which would add these lists also to the table of contents. But don't use both!

Comment: Nice! With the info in your answer, I was able to find this answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1824/88710 to add also the bookmarks to lot and lof

Comment: The second mandatory argument of `\pdfbookmark` is used to generate a unique anchor for the bookmark. I would not use `\contentsname`, depending on the language, it might contain "funny" stuff. Therefore, a plain ASCII letter string like "toc" avoids this. Example: `\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{toc}`

Comment: Neither of these methods makes any difference in my document.

Comment: @spraff Have you tested my example? Do you see the difference there? Are you using a package that is slightly incompatible with KOMA-Script and should not be used? If so, please add it to the MWE in your question.

Comment: I tested your example. Thanks for the suggestion but the other method worked for me so I accepted it.